# Specifying field type as DateTime when exporting (save feature as...) QGIS virtual layer

Tags: qgis, export, sqlite, virtual-layer

To extract useful data from CSV file I use virtual layer. As virtual layer are based on SQLite all field in my virtual layer are of type int, real or text.

These data need to be exported in an ESRI File Geodatabase but when using `Export>Save feature As...` I can't find a way to specify that some text field should be exported as datetime field.

On the "Select fields to export and their export options" section of the export dialog the `Type` column is empty and can't be filled.

On the "Layer Options" section of the export dialog there is a `COLUMN_TYPES` field but I can't figure the correct syntax (I dit try to use the same syntax as in a .cvst file (comma separated field type list) or a comma separated list in the form of `FieldName:FieldType`)

What is the right way to set the field type in the export dialog ?

[image]